# How to add a picture on left and right of the row in Bootstrap 5 for responsivess

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My code is mentioned below but it's in bootstrap 3. I want to have two pictures on the left and right side of the page as shown in the picture below. How can I give space between them to make it responsive

[Picture of the row I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25atb.png)

The code in bootstrap is shown below.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row opacity">
                        
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  Opa">                        
                      <img src="./img/cr-logo.png" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">                     
                      
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                 <div class="img">
                    <img src="./img/appointment.png" class="img-responsive">
                 </div>
                    </div>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The title says Bootstrap 5, the question says 3 and the tags say Bootstrap 4. WTF?

Comment: I have reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is enough. Those extra `div` tags aren't required. By the way I suggest to use Bootstrap 4 or above and I used Bootstrap 4.

- `justify-content-between` - It will display the flex items with space-between.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x100" class="">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100" class="">
   </div>
</div>
```